# Cleaning up files from table without deleting rows in postgresql 9.6.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with files and various relations to this table, files are stored as `bytea`. I want to free up space occupied by old files (according to timestamp), however the rows should still be present in the table.

Is it enough to set `null` to `bytea` field? Will the data be actually deleted from the table this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, updating a row creates a new *tuple* (row version), and the old one is left to be deleted by autovacuum.

Also, larger `bytea` attributes will be stored out-of-line in the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) table that belongs to the table.

When you set the `bytea` attribute to NULL (which is the right thing to do), two things will happen:

- The main table will become **bigger** because of all the new tuples created by the `UPDATE`. Autovacuum will free the space, but not shrink the table (the empty space can be re-used by future data modifications).
- Entries in the TOAST table will be deleted. Again, autovacuum will free the space, but the table won't shrink.

So what you will actually observe is that after the `UPDATE`, your table uses **more space than before**.

You can get rid of all that empty space by running `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table, but that will block concurrent access to the table for the duration of the operation, so be ready to schedule some down time (you'll probably do that for the `UPDATE` anyway).